# Possible full automatic way to install an apk on android device

Tags: android, deployment, installation

I have build an Xamarin.Forms App for a Android based devices. 
This Android device has a USB Port, WiFi and Ethernet.
Now I am looking for a way to deploy this apk full automatically on such devices. 
The best Case would be something like a autorun Script or some mechanism that makes it possible to deploy from USB or similar.

The Deploy Progress should work full automatic without User interaction. What for possibilites do I have to realize it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fortunately, there is no such posibility, it would be serious security problem if there would be such way (just think .. someone can build an USB charger which would infect device only by connecting to it)

Comment: The Point is, that I am working together with the manufactor and I don't want to let the Customer tell Device Secrets to get to Settings Page.